# Complex sequences converging to zero is a subset of $l_{p}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the inclusion $S\subset l_{p},$ where $p\in[1,\infty)$ and

$S=\{a|\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{p}a_{n}=0\quad\forall p\in\mathbb{N}\}.$

I'm stuck solving this. The idea that I used was Hölder Inequality with $n^{-p}$ and $n^p a_{n}$  but I don't get something useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: There's something missing in the description of $S$. Does $S$ consists of those sequences $a$ for which $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^p a_n$ exists?

Comment: Sorry @kobe. My mistake. Is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in S$ then $\lim_n n^2 a_n = 0$ and so there is some $K$ such that $n^2 |a_n| \le K$ for all $n$.

Then we have $|a_n| \le {K \over n^2}$.

Hence $\sum_n |a_n|^p \le K \sum_n {1 \over n^{2p}} \le K \sum_n {1 \over n^{2}} < \infty$ and so $a \in l_p$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. The proof is very clear and elegant.